# Codeigniter : Logout issue

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, smarty, grocery-crud

I am not actually login in to the page.But when i click on the services on index page  for more services ,  show logout button instead of login.Please provide solution for this issue.

Controller:

```
public function more_services($serviceid)
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('realpropertiesmodel');
        $data['service']=$this->realpropertiesmodel->getServicesbyID($serviceid);

        $this->smarty->view('service/service_viewdetails.tpl',$data);

    }
public function logout()
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $data = $this->data;
            redirect("realestate/index" ,'refresh');

        }
```

In the view i add the following code:

```
[~if $id==''~] 
 [~include file="common/realestate_header.tpl"~]
 [~else~]
 [~include file="home/realestate_header.tpl"~]
 [~/if~]
```

But i got the same error when add this much f code.Please provide solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

your `id` variable might be `false` so your check with `""` might fail.

**First solution:**

Change the `id` variable as `-1` if no login information is present:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
$id= $this->session->userdata('id');
$id = ($id) ? $id : -1;
$this->load->model('realpropertiesmodel');
```

And then check for:

```
[~if $id!=-1~]
```

**Second solution**

Directly check for `false`:

```
[~if $id==false~]
```